# How write file length in another file using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline, counting

I am attempting to write a file which compares the amounts of permutations available for three numbers. The current script is

```
tmp = open("tmp_out.txt","w+")
out = open("output_trip.txt", "w")
N = 4
for k in range(2,N+1):
    count = 1
    for j in range(1,k):
        for i in range(0,j):
            tmp.write("({},{},{})\n".format(i,j,k))
            count = len(tmp.readlines())
    out.write('{}{:10d}\n'.format(k,count))
```

The desired output is something like

```
2      1
3      4
4      10
```

However, when I `cat` my outfile, I just get

```
2      0
3      0
4      0
```

When I try `readline()` outside of the loop, it counts one file appropriately, but I need it for more than one value. Is it something simple I'm missing?

I tried many variations of counting I found online but none of them would work in the loop. I've included just the simplest for this exercise.

I can just write a bash script to count which may be the easiest but I would prefer to get it done in python.

Comment: Would it be okay or a problem to compute the permutations?
 Is it necessary to output them?
What happens if you print count or the len?
Have you tried closing the tmp file before reading?

Comment: In this code, the current file position is always at the *end* of the file.  Reading lines starting at the end of the file is going to read zero lines, no matter how many lines there might be earlier in the file.  `tmp.seek(0)` to rewind to the beginning of the file would be one solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

jasonharper was correct. All it took was including tmp.seek(0) before the count to work. The correct version is:

> ```
> N = 4
> for k in range(2,N+1):
> count = 1
> for j in range(1,k):
>     for i in range(0,j):
>         tmp.write("({},{},{})\n".format(i,j,k))
>         tmp.seek(0)
>         count = len(tmp.readlines())
> out.write('{}{:10d}\n'.format(k,count))
> ```

This code prints the number of ordered triples with a set upper limit (in this case 4). The structure of the original code writes the output of the function into a new file, then reads the file to check the length. However, after the loop is run, `readlines()` is at the end of the file. This is why it was giving 0's for every value; there were no lines left at the end. It is necessary to reset to the beginning using `tmp.seek(0)` which then appropriately counts the lines (and thus the number of ordered triples for each value of N).